# Group by and calculate date difference with the group, for first row consider first day of the starting year

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a data frame where I need  to group by type and year to calculate date difference within the group.

Input

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['type1', 'type1', 'type1','type1','type1','type3','type3','type3','type3'],
                   'date': ['2017-3-30','2017-5-10','2017-12-15','2018-01-15','2018-05-01','2018-01-30','2018-06-27','2019-03-20','2019-05-21'],
                   'year': [2017, 2017, 2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019]})


    type        date  year
0  type1   2017-3-30  2017
1  type1   2017-5-10  2017
2  type1  2017-12-15  2017
3  type1  2018-01-15  2018
4  type1  2018-05-01  2018
5  type3  2018-01-30  2018
6  type3  2018-06-27  2018
7  type3  2019-03-20  2019
8  type3  2019-05-21  2019
```

I have tried below solution which gives me date diff for rows, but I want to consider for first date of year for first row within group

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1['DateDiff'] = df1.groupby(['type','year']).date.diff().fillna(0)
```

I am able to achieve below output, which doesn't solve my requirement need to calculate difference for first row value with first day of the year.

```
    type       date  year DateDiff
0  type1 2017-03-30  2017   0 days
1  type1 2017-05-10  2017  41 days
2  type1 2017-12-15  2017 219 days
3  type1 2018-01-15  2018   0 days
4  type1 2018-05-01  2018 106 days
5  type3 2018-01-30  2018   0 days
6  type3 2018-06-27  2018 148 days
7  type3 2019-03-20  2019   0 days
8  type3 2019-05-21  2019  62 days
```

desired output is:

```
    type       date  year DateDiff
0  type1 2017-03-30  2017  88 days ---- (2017 - 01- 01) - (2017 - 03 - 30)
1  type1 2017-05-10  2017  41 days ---- (2017 - 03 - 30) - (2017-05-10)
2  type1 2017-12-15  2017 219 days
3  type1 2018-01-15  2018   14 days ---- (2018-01-01) - (2018-01-15)
4  type1 2018-05-01  2018 106 days
5  type3 2018-01-30  2018   29 days
6  type3 2018-06-27  2018 148 days
7  type3 2019-03-20  2019   78 days
8  type3 2019-05-21  2019  62 days
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you agree with it or comment if anything is missin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more elegant ways, but please find below my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['type1', 'type1', 'type1','type1','type1','type3','type3','type3','type3'],
                   'date': ['2017-3-30','2017-5-10','2017-12-15','2018-01-15','2018-05-01','2018-01-30','2018-06-27','2019-03-20','2019-05-21'],
                   'year': [2017, 2017, 2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
result_lst = []
for year_type, sub_df in df.groupby(['year', 'type']):
    year, type = year_type
    sub_df['shift'] = sub_df['date'].shift(1)
    sub_df.loc[sub_df.index[0], 'shift'] = pd.to_datetime(str(year), format='%Y')
    sub_df['DateDiff'] = sub_df['date'] - sub_df['shift']
    sub_df['year'] = year
    sub_df['type'] = type
    sub_df = sub_df.drop(columns=['shift'])
    result_lst.append(sub_df)
df = pd.concat(result_lst, axis=0)
print(df)
```

The result corresponds to what you were aiming for.